# Save my angular 2 Form data into SQL database through php

Tags: sql, angular

I am new to angular. Can someone recommend me a Tutorial or guide me to connect my angular 2 app to SQL database using PHP and How to retrieve the data from it?

Comment: There is no such thing as a **SQL database** - SQL is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems, but it's not a database product. Many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know **what database system** (and which version) you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Look I googled it for you! :) [google results](https://www.google.fi/search?q=integrate+php+and+angular&oq=integrate+php+and+angular&aqs=chrome..69i57.7872j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=integrate+php+and+angular+2)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do :

1. Use any framework (Laravel, Yii) to Write your API's in PHP. (API's will be used to interact with SQL Database)
2. Create and Angular service to call those API endpoints.
3. Use DI(Dependency Injection) to Call those service function in
   Angular    components.

Hope this will help.